# Using image as border

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use the attached image as border of the div but failed.

My code is

```
<div class="menu-box-wrapper">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu-box-wrapper{
border-image:url(../images/about-text-bg-box.png) 30 repeat stretch;
height:100px;
width:100px;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/gunj1nxj/1/

[image: Image to be used as border]

Comment: Adding a ```border-width``` should help

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/gunj1nxj/3/) what you want?

Comment: Thanks @Lal. It seems the image has been distorted.

Comment: @Lal Quite close https://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/gunj1nxj/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work:

```
.menu-box-wrapper{
    border: 20px solid transparent;
    border-image: url(http://s30.postimg.org/w2z6ws0h9/about_text_bg_box.png?noCache=1431183351) 7 repeat stretch;
    padding: 15px;
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    background:#000;
}
h1{
    color:#fff;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Danthejsman/gunj1nxj/4/

Apparently It will only stretch if you do 7 or under, which is half of the image. Of course, I don't know for sure. Change the border width for a bigger image

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 'repeat' in your css, alter your border-image-slice value in you css code. Not sure what your desired outcome is, but if you alter your code as shown below and play with the values, you should be able to achieve what you are after. Your current code only places the border images at each corner.

```
.menu-box-wrapper{
border: 5px solid transparent;
border-image:url(../images/about-text-bg-box.png) 30% stretch;
background:#ccc;
}
```